# My lower bound binary search function acts like an upper bound binary search function

Tags: python, binary-search

This is my code:

```
def lowbound(num,alist): 
    low = 0
    high = len(alist)-1
    while low < high:
        mid = (high+low)//2
        if num <= alist[mid]:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return low
print(lowbound(4,[1,3,5,7,9]))
```

When I run this, I get 2. How can I make the function such that I get 1, which is the index below the value I'm looking for?

Comment: Why should the result be 1? Because 1 is the index of the value 3 which is the highest value lower than 4?

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased my question and edited mid

Comment: You should be careful with terminology. Ideally you'd use the word 'index' for the array index and 'value' for the value at a given array index. Both are numbers. Don't use the word 'number' here.

Comment: After exiting the loop, `low` may be one higher than the desired value.  So check if alist[low] > num`, and if so, return `low-1`.  Note that if `low` is `0`, and that element is `> num`, it will return `-1`.  Also, if you really want it to be bulletproof, check if `alist` is empty up front, and return something appropriate in that case.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using mid, I should use index and instead of num I should use value?

Comment: Your post currently says that the result of this function should be 1 "which is the number below the number I'm looking for". If 4 is the number you're looking for then 1 isn't the number below it; 3 is. I think you are searching for the highest value that is below `num` and your function should return the index of that value in the array (which is value 3 at index 1).

Comment: @jarmod thank you, I realized how unclear that was.

Comment: Why not simply subtract 1?

Comment: You can just invert your logic. Round up on mid, set low=mid or high=mid-1. Note that this might benefit from an equality check to exit early.

Comment: @KennyOstrom That returns 0 both for num=1 and for num=2, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Kenny They want the "index below", and index 0 has value 1, which isn't below the value 1. And for example for num=3 and num=4, your modifications do lead to different results as expected (0 and 1). So at the very least, they make it inconsistent.

Comment: Ah well, that's not a possible without creating new notation. I just kind of assumed they were implementing https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left

Comment: @KennyOstrom That's exactly what they did, (except for the `-1` in initializing `high`). And I still think they just need to subtract 1 from the result (and fix that initialization).

Comment: But -1 is a valid index to the last item, in python.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Sure, but in a find-an-index context, it's perfectly fine to use `-1` to represent "there is no such index". Like `str.find` does.